# Testing MSDTC between 2 machines

Tags: windows-server-2008, msdtc, distributed-transactions

Is there a utility in which you can provide 2 machine names and determine whether or not they are configured properly to handle transactions back and forth?

(If this is a better question for another Stack Exchange site, please suggest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DTCPing](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2868) is your friend.  You'll need to run on both machines.